# R help - function on multiple data frame columns

Tags: r, user-defined-functions, dry, tidyverse

I would like to use a function to repeat a set of procedures on four columns in a data frame. Ultimately I need a long data frame containing all the output. Here is my data frame:

```
> sample_data
# A tibble: 10 x 7
      REVENUEID AMOUNT  YEAR REPORT_CODE PAYMENT_METHOD INBOUND_CHANNEL  AMOUNT_CAT
          <chr>  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>          <chr>           <chr>      <fctr>
 1 rev-24985629     30  FY18           S          Check            Mail     [25,50)
 2 rev-22812413      1  FY16           Q          Other      Canvassing   [0.01,10)
 3 rev-23508794    100  FY17           Q    Credit card             Web   [100,250)
 4 rev-23506121    300  FY17           S    Credit card            Mail   [250,500)
 5 rev-23550444    100  FY17           S    Credit card             Web   [100,250)
 6 rev-21508672     25  FY14           J          Check            Mail     [25,50)
 7 rev-24981769    500  FY18           S    Credit card             Web [500,1e+03)
 8 rev-23503684     50  FY17           R          Check            Mail     [50,75)
 9 rev-24982087     25  FY18           R          Check            Mail     [25,50)
10 rev-24979834     50  FY18           R    Credit card             Web     [50,75)
```

Here is my code:

```
AMOUNT_CAT<- sample_data %>% group_by(AMOUNT_CAT,YEAR) %>% summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>% rename(REPORT_VALUE=AMOUNT_CAT) %>% mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY="AMOUNT_CAT")
INBOUND_CHANNEL<- sample_data %>% group_by(INBOUND_CHANNEL,YEAR) %>% summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>% rename(REPORT_VALUE=INBOUND_CHANNEL) %>% mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY="INBOUND_CHANNEL")
PAYMENT_METHOD<- sample_data %>% group_by(PAYMENT_METHOD,YEAR) %>% summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>% rename(REPORT_VALUE=PAYMENT_METHOD) %>% mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY="PAYMENT_METHOD")
REPORT_CODE<- sample_data %>% group_by(REPORT_CODE,YEAR) %>% summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>% rename(REPORT_VALUE=REPORT_CODE) %>% mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY="REPORT_CODE")
final_product<-bind_rows(REPORT_CODE,PAYMENT_METHOD,INBOUND_CHANNEL,AMOUNT_CAT)
```

Here is the final product of that code:

```
       > final_product
        # A tibble: 27 x 5
        # Groups:   REPORT_VALUE [16]
           REPORT_CATEGORY REPORT_VALUE  YEAR   num total

                 <chr>        <chr> <chr> <int> <dbl>
     1     REPORT_CODE            J  FY14     1    25
     2     REPORT_CODE            Q  FY16     1     1
     3     REPORT_CODE            Q  FY17     1   100
     4     REPORT_CODE            R  FY17     1    50
     5     REPORT_CODE            R  FY18     2    75
     6     REPORT_CODE            S  FY17     2   400
     7     REPORT_CODE            S  FY18     2   530
     8  PAYMENT_METHOD        Check  FY14     1    25
     9  PAYMENT_METHOD        Check  FY17     1    50
    10  PAYMENT_METHOD        Check  FY18     2    55
    # ... with 17 more rows
```

Here is my attempt to condense the code to make it smarter and more efficient (it doesn't work):

```
cat.list <- c("REPORT_CODE","PAYMENT_METHOD","INBOUND_CHANNEL","AMOUNT_CAT")
repeat_procs <- lapply(cat.list, function(x) x <- sample_data %>% group_by(x,YEAR) %>% summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>% rename(REPORT_VALUE=x) %>% mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY="x")
```

Can someone please advise me on how to write "smarter" code that doesn't repeat as often?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the strings to symbols (`rlang::sym`) and unquote them in `group_by` and `rename` like the following. Another thing to note is that your `cat.list` is already a string vector, so there is no need to add double quotes around `x` in `mutate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

cat.list <- c("REPORT_CODE","PAYMENT_METHOD","INBOUND_CHANNEL","AMOUNT_CAT")
repeat_procs <- lapply(cat.list, function(x){
  final_data <- sample_data %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(x), YEAR) %>% 
    summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>% 
    rename(REPORT_VALUE=!!sym(x)) %>% 
    mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY=x)
}) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

**Result:**

```
> repeat_procs
# A tibble: 27 x 5
# Groups:   REPORT_VALUE [16]
   REPORT_VALUE   YEAR   num total REPORT_CATEGORY
          <chr> <fctr> <int> <int>           <chr>
 1            J   FY14     1    25     REPORT_CODE
 2            Q   FY16     1     1     REPORT_CODE
 3            Q   FY17     1   100     REPORT_CODE
 4            R   FY17     1    50     REPORT_CODE
 5            R   FY18     2    75     REPORT_CODE
 6            S   FY17     2   400     REPORT_CODE
 7            S   FY18     2   530     REPORT_CODE
 8        Check   FY14     1    25  PAYMENT_METHOD
 9        Check   FY17     1    50  PAYMENT_METHOD
10        Check   FY18     2    55  PAYMENT_METHOD
# ... with 17 more rows
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, useR for teaching me a better way to code in tidyverse - Is there anywhere in particular, other than in SO answers, that I can read more about this approach? I am not seeing anything in particular in all the `rlang` or `lazyeval` materials.

Comment: @JensLeerssen In this particular case, yutannihilation's method of "tidying" the data before grouping might be a better approach, but tidy evaluation can be very useful in a lot of other cases. I see that you have looked into "Programming in dplyr", but found it difficult to understand. See if this page would help you a bit more: https://edwinth.github.io/blog/dplyr-recipes/. It has several common tidy eval examples.

Comment: Thank you! The `character to name: sym (edited)` section and the edits section at the bottom about names is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For more "smarter" code, you need to transform the data to ["tidy data"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) form before grouping and summarizing.

```r
data_tidy <-
  tidyr::gather(sample_data, key = "REPORT_CATEGORY", value = "REPORT_VALUE", !! cat.list)

data_tidy
#>       REVENUEID AMOUNT YEAR REPORT_CATEGORY REPORT_VALUE
#> 1  rev-24985629     30 FY18     REPORT_CODE            S
#> 2  rev-22812413      1 FY16     REPORT_CODE            Q
#> 3  rev-23508794    100 FY17     REPORT_CODE            Q
#> 4  rev-23506121    300 FY17     REPORT_CODE            S
#> 5  rev-23550444    100 FY17     REPORT_CODE            S
#> 6  rev-21508672     25 FY14     REPORT_CODE            J
#> 7  rev-24981769    500 FY18     REPORT_CODE            S
#> 8  rev-23503684     50 FY17     REPORT_CODE            R
#> 9  rev-24982087     25 FY18     REPORT_CODE            R
#> 10 rev-24979834     50 FY18     REPORT_CODE            R
#> 11 rev-24985629     30 FY18  PAYMENT_METHOD        Check
#> 12 rev-22812413      1 FY16  PAYMENT_METHOD        Other
#> 13 rev-23508794    100 FY17  PAYMENT_METHOD  Credit card
#> 14 rev-23506121    300 FY17  PAYMENT_METHOD  Credit card
#> 15 rev-23550444    100 FY17  PAYMENT_METHOD  Credit card
#> 16 rev-21508672     25 FY14  PAYMENT_METHOD        Check
#> 17 rev-24981769    500 FY18  PAYMENT_METHOD  Credit card
#> 18 rev-23503684     50 FY17  PAYMENT_METHOD        Check
#> 19 rev-24982087     25 FY18  PAYMENT_METHOD        Check
#> 20 rev-24979834     50 FY18  PAYMENT_METHOD  Credit card
#> 21 rev-24985629     30 FY18 INBOUND_CHANNEL         Mail
#> 22 rev-22812413      1 FY16 INBOUND_CHANNEL   Canvassing
#> 23 rev-23508794    100 FY17 INBOUND_CHANNEL          Web
#> 24 rev-23506121    300 FY17 INBOUND_CHANNEL         Mail
#> 25 rev-23550444    100 FY17 INBOUND_CHANNEL          Web
#> 26 rev-21508672     25 FY14 INBOUND_CHANNEL         Mail
#> 27 rev-24981769    500 FY18 INBOUND_CHANNEL          Web
#> 28 rev-23503684     50 FY17 INBOUND_CHANNEL         Mail
#> 29 rev-24982087     25 FY18 INBOUND_CHANNEL         Mail
#> 30 rev-24979834     50 FY18 INBOUND_CHANNEL          Web
#> 31 rev-24985629     30 FY18      AMOUNT_CAT      [25,50)
#> 32 rev-22812413      1 FY16      AMOUNT_CAT    [0.01,10)
#> 33 rev-23508794    100 FY17      AMOUNT_CAT    [100,250)
#> 34 rev-23506121    300 FY17      AMOUNT_CAT    [250,500)
#> 35 rev-23550444    100 FY17      AMOUNT_CAT    [100,250)
#> 36 rev-21508672     25 FY14      AMOUNT_CAT      [25,50)
#> 37 rev-24981769    500 FY18      AMOUNT_CAT  [500,1e+03)
#> 38 rev-23503684     50 FY17      AMOUNT_CAT      [50,75)
#> 39 rev-24982087     25 FY18      AMOUNT_CAT      [25,50)
#> 40 rev-24979834     50 FY18      AMOUNT_CAT      [50,75)

data_tidy %>%
  group_by(REPORT_CATEGORY, REPORT_VALUE, YEAR) %>%
  summarise(num = n(), total = sum(AMOUNT)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 27 x 5
#>    REPORT_CATEGORY REPORT_VALUE  YEAR   num total
#>              <chr>        <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
#>  1      AMOUNT_CAT    [0.01,10)  FY16     1     1
#>  2      AMOUNT_CAT    [100,250)  FY17     2   200
#>  3      AMOUNT_CAT      [25,50)  FY14     1    25
#>  4      AMOUNT_CAT      [25,50)  FY18     2    55
#>  5      AMOUNT_CAT    [250,500)  FY17     1   300
#>  6      AMOUNT_CAT      [50,75)  FY17     1    50
#>  7      AMOUNT_CAT      [50,75)  FY18     1    50
#>  8      AMOUNT_CAT  [500,1e+03)  FY18     1   500
#>  9 INBOUND_CHANNEL   Canvassing  FY16     1     1
#> 10 INBOUND_CHANNEL         Mail  FY14     1    25
#> # ... with 17 more rows
```

Comment: Nice! I am starting to recognize that whenever a `split, apply, combine` is requested, there is aways a far simpler `tidy` approach that should be found.

Answer (score 0):

A `purrr` approach added to make your code a little conciser and `smarter`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang) 
cat.list <- c("REPORT_CODE","PAYMENT_METHOD","INBOUND_CHANNEL","AMOUNT_CAT")

map_df(cat.list,
       function(report_cat) {
           sample_data %>%
               group_by(!!sym(report_cat), YEAR) %>%
               summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>% 
               rename(REPORT_VALUE = !!sym(report_cat)) %>% 
               mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY = report_cat)
       }
      )
```

As Hadley describes [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/lists.html) (about halfway down):

> `map_df(x, f)` is effectively the same as `do.call("rbind", lapply(x, f))` but under the hood is much more efficient.

Full disclosure, Thank you @useR for showing me how to use the `sym(!!()` approach.  I had backed myself into a corner using the [`Programming in Dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) vignette to construct what I believed was the most up to date approach to functionalizing `dplyr`. 
I had gotten the main `dplyr` function to run smoothly enough using `var <- enquo(var)` then `!!var`s  but I could not find a way to then deal with running the quoted names in `cat.list` through `map_df` or `lapply`. 
Thank you, useR for teaching me a better way to code in tidyverse

Edit: Thank you, G. Grothendieck for unlocking how to get a list of strings to smoothly be accepted by the dplyr function: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47319955/5088194)

That allows me to complete the alternative quosured approach I had developed earlier:

```
report <- function(report_cat){
    report_cat <- enquo(report_cat)
    sample_data %>%
    group_by(!!report_cat, YEAR) %>%
    summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>% 
    rename(REPORT_VALUE = !!report_cat) %>% 
    mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY := as.character(quote(!!report_cat))[2])
}
report_named <- function(x) {do.call("report", list(as.name(x)))}
map_df(cat.list, report_named)
```

> ```
> > map_df(cat.list, report_named)
>     # A tibble: 27 x 5
>     # Groups:   REPORT_VALUE [16]
>        REPORT_VALUE  YEAR   num total REPORT_CATEGORY
>               <chr> <chr> <int> <int>           <chr>
>      1            J  FY14     1    25     REPORT_CODE
>      2            Q  FY16     1     1     REPORT_CODE
>      3            Q  FY17     1   100     REPORT_CODE
>      4            R  FY17     1    50     REPORT_CODE
>      5            R  FY18     2    75     REPORT_CODE
>      6            S  FY17     2   400     REPORT_CODE
>      7            S  FY18     2   530     REPORT_CODE
>      8        Check  FY14     1    25  PAYMENT_METHOD
>      9        Check  FY17     1    50  PAYMENT_METHOD
>     10        Check  FY18     2    55  PAYMENT_METHOD
>     # ... with 17 more rows
> ```

**NB: yutannihilation's tidy solution really is the optimal solution IMHO** - I was just using this as an opportunity to expand my understanding of how we can carry along the *split, apply, combine* approach to include `dplyr` functions.