# How to feed a list of unquoted column names into `lapply` (so that I can use it with a `dplyr` function)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang, lazyeval

I am trying to write a function in `tidyverse/dplyr` that I want to eventually use with `lapply` (or `map`). (I had been working on it to [answer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47315053/r-help-function-on-multiple-data-frame-columns/47316151?noredirect=1#comment81588634_47316151), but came upon an interesting result/dead-end. Please don't mark this as a duplicate - this question is an extension/departure from the answers that you see there.)

*Is there*
**1) a way to get a list of quoted variables to work inside a dplyr function**
(and not use the deprecated `SE_` functions)  *or is there*
**2) some way to feed a list of unquoted strings through an `lapply` or `map`**

I have used the [`Programming in Dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) vignette to construct what I believe is a function most in line with the current standard
for working with the NSE.

#### The sample data:

```
sample_data <- 
    read.table(text = "REVENUEID AMOUNT  YEAR REPORT_CODE PAYMENT_METHOD INBOUND_CHANNEL  AMOUNT_CAT
               1 rev-24985629     30  FY18           S          Check            Mail     25,50
               2 rev-22812413      1  FY16           Q          Other      Canvassing   0.01,10
               3 rev-23508794    100  FY17           Q    Credit_card             Web   100,250
               4 rev-23506121    300  FY17           S    Credit_card            Mail   250,500
               5 rev-23550444    100  FY17           S    Credit_card             Web   100,250
               6 rev-21508672     25  FY14           J          Check            Mail     25,50
               7 rev-24981769    500  FY18           S    Credit_card             Web 500,1e+03
               8 rev-23503684     50  FY17           R          Check            Mail     50,75
               9 rev-24982087     25  FY18           R          Check            Mail     25,50
               10 rev-24979834     50  FY18           R    Credit_card             Web    50,75
                      ", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

#### A report generating function

```
report <- function(report_cat){
    report_cat <- enquo(report_cat)
    sample_data %>%
    group_by(!!report_cat, YEAR) %>%
    summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>% 
    rename(REPORT_VALUE = !!report_cat) %>% 
    mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY := as.character(quote(!!report_cat))[2])
}
```

Which works fine for generating a single report:

> ```
> > report(REPORT_CODE)
> # A tibble: 7 x 5
> # Groups:   REPORT_VALUE [4]
>   REPORT_VALUE  YEAR   num total REPORT_CATEGORY
>          <chr> <chr> <int> <int>           <chr>
> 1            J  FY14     1    25     REPORT_CODE
> 2            Q  FY16     1     1     REPORT_CODE
> 3            Q  FY17     1   100     REPORT_CODE
> 4            R  FY17     1    50     REPORT_CODE
> 5            R  FY18     2    75     REPORT_CODE
> 6            S  FY17     2   400     REPORT_CODE
> 7            S  FY18     2   530     REPORT_CODE
> ```

It is when I try and set up a list of all 4 of the reports to generate, that everything breaks down. (Though admittedly the code required in that last line of the function - to return a string with which to then fill the column - should be clue enough that I have wandered off in the wrong direction.)

```
#the other reports
cat.list <- c("REPORT_CODE","PAYMENT_METHOD","INBOUND_CHANNEL","AMOUNT_CAT")

# Applying and Mapping attempts 
lapply(cat.list, report)
map_df(cat.list, report)
```

Which results in:

> ```
> > lapply(cat.list, report)  
>  Error in (function (x, strict = TRUE)  : 
>   the argument has already been evaluated  
>
> > map_df(cat.list, report)
>  Error in (function (x, strict = TRUE)  : 
>   the argument has already been evaluated
> ```

I have also tried to convert the list of strings to names before handing it over to `apply` and `map`:

```
library(rlang)
cat.names <- lapply(cat.list, sym)
lapply(cat.names, report)
map_df(cat.names, report)
```

> ```
> > lapply(cat.names, report)
>  Error in (function (x, strict = TRUE)  : 
>   the argument has already been evaluated 
> > map_df(cat.names, report)
>  Error in (function (x, strict = TRUE)  : 
>   the argument has already been evaluated
> ```

In any case, the reason I am asking this question is that I think that I have written the function to the currently documented standards, but ultimately I can then see no way to utilize a member of the `apply` or even of the `purrr::map` family with such a function. Short of rewriting the function to use `names` like *useR* has done here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47316151/5088194 is there a way to get this function to work with `apply` or `map`?

I am hoping to see this as a result:

> ```
> # A tibble: 27 x 5
> # Groups:   REPORT_VALUE [16]
>    REPORT_VALUE  YEAR   num total REPORT_CATEGORY
>           <chr> <chr> <int> <int>           <chr>
>  1            J  FY14     1    25     REPORT_CODE
>  2            Q  FY16     1     1     REPORT_CODE
>  3            Q  FY17     1   100     REPORT_CODE
>  4            R  FY17     1    50     REPORT_CODE
>  5            R  FY18     2    75     REPORT_CODE
>  6            S  FY17     2   400     REPORT_CODE
>  7            S  FY18     2   530     REPORT_CODE
>  8        Check  FY14     1    25  PAYMENT_METHOD
>  9        Check  FY17     1    50  PAYMENT_METHOD
> 10        Check  FY18     2    55  PAYMENT_METHOD
> # ... with 17 more rows
> ```

Comment: Great follow-up question. See my answer for explanation of `syms` and `quos`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`as.name` will convert a string to a name and that can be passed to `report`:

```
lapply(cat.list, function(x) do.call("report", list(as.name(x))))
```

**character argument** An alternative is to rewrite `report` so that it accepts a character string argument:

```
report_ch <- function(colname) {  
    report_cat <- rlang::sym(colname)   # as.name(colname) would also work here
    sample_data %>%
                group_by(!!report_cat, YEAR) %>%
                summarize(num = n(), total = sum(AMOUNT)) %>% 
                rename(REPORT_VALUE = !!report_cat) %>% 
                mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY = colname)
}

lapply(cat.list, report_ch)
```

**wrapr** An alternate approach is to rewrite `report` using the wrapr package which is an alternative to rlang/tidyeval:

```
library(dplyr)
library(wrapr)

report_wrapr <- function(colname) 
  let(c(COLNAME = colname),
      sample_data %>%
                  group_by(COLNAME, YEAR) %>%
                  summarize(num = n(), total = sum(AMOUNT)) %>%
                  rename(REPORT_VALUE = COLNAME) %>%
                  mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY = colname)
   )

lapply(cat.list, report_wrapr)
```

Of course, this whole problem would go away if you used a different framework, e.g.

**plyr**

```
library(plyr)

report_plyr <- function(colname)
  ddply(sample_data, c(REPORT_VALUE = colname, "YEAR"), function(x)
     data.frame(num = nrow(x), total = sum(x$AMOUNT), REPORT_CATEOGRY = colname))

lapply(cat.list, report_plyr)
```

**sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)

report_sql <- function(colname, envir = parent.frame(), ...)
  fn$sqldf("select [$colname] REPORT_VALUE,
                   YEAR,
                   count(*) num,
                   sum(AMOUNT) total,
                   '$colname' REPORT_CATEGORY
            from sample_data
            group by [$colname], YEAR", envir = envir, ...)

lapply(cat.list, report_sql)
```

**base - by**

```
report_base_by <- function(colname)
      do.call("rbind", 
        by(sample_data, sample_data[c(colname, "YEAR")], function(x)
            data.frame(REPORT_VALUE = x[1, colname], 
                       YEAR = x$YEAR[1], 
                       num = nrow(x), 
                       total = sum(x$AMOUNT), 
                       REPORT_CATEGORY = colname)
         )
      )

lapply(cat.list, report_base_by)
```

**data.table** The data.table package provides another alternative but that has already been covered by another answer.

**Update:** Added additional alternatives.

Comment: Such a thorough and well crafted collection of solutions. I will continue to unpack these for days - there is so much to learn here. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Let me first point out that in your initial `report` function, you can use `quo_name` to convert the quosure into a string, which you can then use in `mutate` like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

report <- function(report_cat){
  report_cat <- enquo(report_cat)

  sample_data %>%
    group_by(!!report_cat, YEAR) %>%
    summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>%
    rename(REPORT_VALUE = !!report_cat) %>%
    mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY = quo_name(report_cat))
}

report(REPORT_CODE)
```

Now, to address your question of "how to feed a list of unquoted strings through `lapply` or `map` to make it work inside `dplyr` functions", I propose two ways of doing it.

### 1. Use `rlang::sym` to parse your strings and unquote it when feeding into `lapply` or `map`

```
library(purrr)

cat.list <- c("REPORT_CODE","PAYMENT_METHOD","INBOUND_CHANNEL","AMOUNT_CAT")

map_df(cat.list, ~report(!!sym(.)))
```

or with `syms` you can parse all elements of a vector at once:

```
map_df(syms(cat.list), ~report(!!.))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 27 x 5
# Groups:   REPORT_VALUE [16]
   REPORT_VALUE  YEAR   num total REPORT_CATEGORY
          <chr> <chr> <int> <int>           <chr>
 1            J  FY14     1    25     REPORT_CODE
 2            Q  FY16     1     1     REPORT_CODE
 3            Q  FY17     1   100     REPORT_CODE
 4            R  FY17     1    50     REPORT_CODE
 5            R  FY18     2    75     REPORT_CODE
 6            S  FY17     2   400     REPORT_CODE
 7            S  FY18     2   530     REPORT_CODE
 8        Check  FY14     1    25  PAYMENT_METHOD
 9        Check  FY17     1    50  PAYMENT_METHOD
10        Check  FY18     2    55  PAYMENT_METHOD
# ... with 17 more rows
```

### 2. Rewrite your `report` function by placing `lapply` or `map` *inside* so that `report` can do NSE

```
report <- function(...){
  report_cat <- quos(...)

  map_df(report_cat, function(x) sample_data %>%
             group_by(!!x, YEAR) %>%
             summarize(num=n(),total=sum(AMOUNT)) %>%
             rename(REPORT_VALUE = !!x) %>%
             mutate(REPORT_CATEGORY = quo_name(x)))
}
```

By placing `map_df` inside `report`, you can take advantage of `quos`, which converts `...` to list of quosures. They are then fed into `map_df` and unquoted one by one using `!!`.

```
report(REPORT_CODE, PAYMENT_METHOD, INBOUND_CHANNEL, AMOUNT_CAT)
```

Another advantage of writing it like this is that you can also supply a vector of string symbols and splice them using `!!!` like the following:

```
report(!!!syms(cat.list))
```

**Result:**

```
# A tibble: 27 x 5
# Groups:   REPORT_VALUE [16]
   REPORT_VALUE  YEAR   num total REPORT_CATEGORY
          <chr> <chr> <int> <int>           <chr>
 1            J  FY14     1    25     REPORT_CODE
 2            Q  FY16     1     1     REPORT_CODE
 3            Q  FY17     1   100     REPORT_CODE
 4            R  FY17     1    50     REPORT_CODE
 5            R  FY18     2    75     REPORT_CODE
 6            S  FY17     2   400     REPORT_CODE
 7            S  FY18     2   530     REPORT_CODE
 8        Check  FY14     1    25  PAYMENT_METHOD
 9        Check  FY17     1    50  PAYMENT_METHOD
10        Check  FY18     2    55  PAYMENT_METHOD
# ... with 17 more rows
```

Comment: Wow, I think I have already learned 7 new things and I am only about half way through all of your solutions. So many interesting layers to consider.  I think I am starting to recognize why functional programming is spoken of in such reverential tones. Thank you!

Comment: @JensLeerssen Glad that it helped. You always learn something everyday :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really a dplyr afficionado, but for what its worth here is how you could achieve this using `library(data.table)` instead:

```
setDT(sample_data)

gen_report <- function(report_cat){
  sample_data[ , .(num = .N, total = sum(AMOUNT), REPORT_CATEGORY = report_cat), 
               by = .(REPORT_VALUE = get(report_cat), YEAR)] 
}

gen_report('REPORT_CODE')
lapply(cat.list, gen_report)
```